# Android. как прочитать Preferences

Tags: java, android

Не работает.

```
SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;
int scorerecord = 0;
pref = context.getSharedPreferences("recordmeasure",Context.MODE_APPEND);

editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("recordmeasure",scorerecord);
            editor.commit();

 scorerecord=pref.getInt("recordmeasure",9);
```

Если в функции `pref.getInt("recordmeasure",9);` допустить ошибку в названии ключа "recordmeasure" то выводится 9 (ответ по умолчанию если ключ не существует), то есть переменная вроде как создается "recordmeasure" но почему то ничего туда не записывается, и при вызове по ключу - постоянно ответ - ноль.

Comment: Ответ Ноль - даже когда переменная scorerecord меняется перед записью

Comment: А вы точно меняете `scorerecord` перед записью? Выглядит так как быдто вы записываете 0 и получаете 0.

Comment: я удалил ненужный код чтоб не путался под ногами, но даже когда переменную иннициализирую при создангии в любое другое число - всеровно на выходе ноль. То есть ноль - присваивается где то

Comment: Добавь лог перед `editor.putInt("recordmeasure",scorerecord);` и посмотри что там сохраняется. Проверь что у тебя где-то в другом месте не вызывается `editor.putInt("recordmeasure", something);` с тем же ключом. Ну и ты как бы покажи код в котором у тебя работа с `scorerecord`, а то оно где-то обнуляется, а где - не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.getSharedPreferences("recordmeasure",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

MODE_APPEND вообще не про преференсы.

Comment: .MODE_PRIVATE тоже пробывал